Finding an orthonormal basis such that certain unitary operators are represented by matrices with few non-zero entries
Let $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a hermitian inner product space. Let $\mathcal{T} \subseteq U(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a finite set of unitary operators on $V$. Given a basis $\mathcal{B}$, let $M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}(T)$ be the representation matrix of $T$ with respect to the matrix $\mathcal{B}$. Let
$$
n_{\mathcal{B}} = \sum\limits_{T \in \mathcal{T}} \text{number of nonzero entries in } M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}(T)
$$
and
$$
m_{\mathcal{B}} = \underset{T \in \mathcal{T}}{\operatorname{max}} \left( \text{number of nonzero entries in } M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}(T) \right)
$$
Questions:

How can we algorithmically find an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ that minimizes $n_{\mathcal{B}}$?

How can we algorithmically find an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ that minimizes $m_{\mathcal{B}}$?


The motivation behind this is that we take $\rho: G \to U(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ to be a finite-dimensional unitary representation of a finite group $G$. Then $G$ is represented via the matrices $\mathcal{T} = \{\rho(g) \mid g \in G\}$. We want to find a "nice" orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$, meaning one where there are few nonzero entries in the matrices, in order to understand the representation better.

my instinct would say, as a greedy heuristic, take the basis where $T_i$ is diagonal and choose the best over those
